# Reselect: how to cache data written to a reducer?

Tags: reactjs

I try to reselect and immediately got up the problem: data polling works. Almost every time the same data arrives in the reducer — a component rerender occurs using this data. I try to cache this data with the selector — fails — the rerender still happens. What is wrong with this code?

```
function getAllTickets(reducer) {
    return reducer.get('tickets');
}

export const allTicketsSelector = createSelector([getAllTickets], items => items);
```

Comment: What does `reducer.get` do? It might return a new object on every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the surface comparison [function](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/ac77610bbb0a3cab9b280ea5ea379c2387017446/src/index.js#L1) is used in createSelector. Want to make a deep comparison, use createSelectorCreator and your comparison function. There is an example in the [documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#customize-equalitycheck-for-defaultmemoize).